# Failed to read row 1, column 1 from CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 1 columns

Tags: android

this might be a simple question for some of you guys,i want to list all values of a colmun, here im using this query :

```
  Cursor c = null;
   ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>() ; 
   c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT username FROM contacts",null);  
   c.moveToFirst();
   while (c.moveToNext()) {
   for(int j=0;j<c.getCount();j++){


         names.add(c.getString(j));
}  


  }
```

and im getting this

```
 06-14 06:36:56.017: E/CursorWindow(2608): Failed to read row 1, column 1 from a   
 CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 1 columns.
```

and when i put while condition inside the for loop, i get just last item in the column. what is the problem?

Comment: remove c.moveToFirst();

Comment: then it returns     06-14 07:07:49.897: E/CursorWindow(10831): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 1 columns.
    obvoiusly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
   for(int j=0;j<c.getCount();j++){
      names.add(c.getString(j));
}
```

`c.getCount()` will return the number of rows in the cursor. So you should not use it to loop in the columns. Each row will only include one column which is username. So you can access it directly with index position.

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
   names.add(c.getString(0));
   // or better
   names.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("username")));
}
```

Comment: @user3694470. just `thanks alot` did not work. If it work for you accept as Ans.

Comment: actually this returned the first row twice, but thanks it helped

Comment: Of course it will return twice. I wrote to different ways to get the result in different ways. Just comment out one of the lines :)

Answer (score 1):

If you see you code, you are reading only one columns `username` so you don't need the inner `for` loop. just use `do while` loop. Do some thing like below

```
.   
.
 c.moveToFirst();
 if(c.getCount()>0){
   do{
      names.add(c.getString(0));
   }while(c.moveToNext());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when you're trying to return an index that is out of bound for example I was doing the following

```
return word + "\r\n" + mCur.getString(2);
```

where I had only 2 rows. Silly mistake.